# Is invoke virtual always dynamically bind?

Tags: java

Today one of my friend told me that,if a instruction is invoke virtual it is always dynamically bind,whereas invoke special is always statically bind? is it true?

if yes then why does when a method with final keyword is also invoke virtual?

please clarify this doubt that i have

Answer (score 8):

In essence, yes you are correct.  The fun part was the introduction of Hotspot.  Hotspot is essentially another compiler, and it knows which classes are currently loaded and even more scaringly it knows when new classes are loaded and can recompile with that updated knowledge on the fly.  Hotspot may choose to perform optimizations that remove dynamic dispatch, using knowledge not available to javac.  When Hotspot was added, the code in javac was simplified.  Sun stripped out a lot of logic, mostly the optimization parts.

So to answer your question, javac does not pay a huge amount of attention to final keywords for methods.  It defers to its bigger brother, Hotspot.

Oracle documents some of these optimizations performed by Hotspot here: https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PerformanceTechniques.  Have a look under the section for methods.

Answer (score 2):

It is more complicated than your friend told you.

The `invokespecial` instruction always gives static (non-dispatched) binding.

The `invoke` instruction gives dynamic binding *as far as you can tell*.  And if you were to run your code using the HotSpot bytecode interpreter (e.g. as forced by `-Xint`) then I expect that the call will always be dispatched.

However, the HotSpot compiler / optimizer is capable of detecting when dispatching is unnecessary.  For example, HotSpot knows about all of the classes that are currently loaded.  If an `invoke` is applied to a method which is not overridden in any loaded classes, it can optimize away the dispatching and perform a direct call instead.  Furthermore, HotSpot is smart enough to undo such an optimization if another class is loaded subsequently that invalidates the optimizer's "no overrides" assumption.

---

> ... why does when a method with final keyword is also invoke virtual?

That is *necessary* because of the binary compatibility rule for `final` methods:

> *"Changing a method that is declared final to no longer be declared final does not break compatibility with pre-existing binaries."*  ([JLS 13.4.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.17))

Suppose that instance method `Foo.a()` is declared as `final` and some code in `Bar` was to invoke the method.  If the bytecode compiler uses an `invokespecial` instruction for the call, then if we changed `Foo.a()` to be not `final` and also added subclasses for `Foo`.  Suppose also that we did not recompile `Bar`.  We could end up with code in `Bar` that used `invokespecial` even though dispatching was necessary.  In other words, we'd have broken binary compatibility for `Bar`'s call to `Foo.a()`.

However, as I explained above, the optimizer can deal with this anyway because it can determine whether dispatching is needed at any call site based on global analysis.