# What type of binding has the following code?

Tags: java, binding

I have read article about early and late binding in java. I understand the concept, but I can't distinguish them in certain situations.

Code №1:

```
class Human {
    public void walk() {
        System.out.println("Human walks");
    }
}

class Boy extends Human {
    public void walk() {
        System.out.println("Boy walks");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Boy obj = new Boy();
        obj.walk();
    }
}
```

Code №2:

```
class Human {
    public void walk() {
        System.out.println("Human walks");
    }
}

public class Boy extends Human {
    public void walk() {
        System.out.println("Boy walks");
    }

    public static void test(Boy obj) {        
        obj.walk();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Boy obj = new Boy();
        test(obj);
    }
}
```

Code №3:

```
class Human {
    public void walk() {
        System.out.println("Human walks");
    }
}

class OldBoy extends Boy {
    public void walk() {
        System.out.println("OldBoy walks");
    }
}

public class Boy extends Human {
    public void walk() {
        System.out.println("Boy walks");
    }

    public static void test(Boy obj) {
        obj.walk();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Boy obj = new Boy();
        test(obj);
    }
}
```

What type of binding (late or early) has the call obj.walk() in Code №1, Code №2 and Code №3? And why?

Comment: This sounds like homework, is this homework? (Note that homework problems aren't banned per se, but you should tell if this is homework or not). Also, what do you think the answers are?

Comment: the `walk` method is not `private`, `final` or `static`. The compiler can therefore not detemine the static type and you got late binding in all cases.

Comment: First of all it isn't a homework. 
Code №1 come from this article http://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/java-static-dynamic-binding/ 
Author said:
"Here we have created an object of Boy class and calling the method walk() of the same class. Since nothing is ambiguous here, compiler would be able to resolve this binding during compile-time, such kind of binding is known as static binding."
So author is wrong?

Comment: depends.. the compile emits the same `invokevirtual #{Boy.walk}` bytecode in all cases and it gets more complicated from there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551648/is-invoke-virtual-always-dynamically-bind - what's your definition of early / late binding? Is it early even if the compiler doesn't use that optimization?